# Running multiple instances of same springboot application

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, ovh, springboot

I've a spring-boot application which i want to deploy on OVH public cloud.

I need t achieve the goal of deploying multiple instances of the same application, and each instance has to have its own resources (such as MySQL database).

Each instance has to be accessed with a special url. For example:

- The first instance is accessable from http://domainname/instance1/index.html
- The second instance is accessable from http://domainname/instance2/index.html

I'm really new to everything which concerns cloud computing and deployments.

From what i read on the internet, my doubt is to

- Use Docker where each instance has to be running inside its own container (to have the resources separated for each instance)
- Use Kubernetes to achieve the goal of having each instance accessable from a specific url.

Am i wrong ? any online courses / resources / videos which can help would be awsome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Stack community!

First of all, I recommend quickly run through the serverfault [tour](https://serverfault.com/tour) for better understanding how to post questions and get desirable answer.

This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum.

In your case, start with reading Kuberenetes [concept](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/) and play with Kubernetes [basics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/#basics). And then, whenever you face a specific problem with deploying your application, you can reach out a community and ask for help.

Still, if you are interested at this point how to manage multiple hosts in K8s, you will need [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting) object which will map each url to a specific backend, i.e.

```
- host:  domainname.instance1.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
  - host: domainname.instance2.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 80
```

Hope to hear from you soon!

Comment: Thanks, ingress was exactly the solution, sorry for late answer, i was reading about all those new things